# How can a brahmin trace his ancestors?

Tags: history, brahmins, ancestry

If one is a Brahmin, how can he trace his ancestors back to say 3-4 generations through gotra (lineage) of atri?

Comment: Associated with each Gotra is one or more sets of Pravaras, which are sets of rishis that a Brahmin belonging to that Gotra belong to.  I say "one or more", because sometimes Gotras have multiple branches.  In any case, the Pravaras will only provide like two or three descendants of Atri that you're descended from.  It doesn't list every single person you're descended from.

Comment: Many families have a vamsha vriksham (family tree). You can ask the oldest person in your family about it whether there is one in your family.

Comment: As already advised by Shri Charan above, many families maintain their family trees in places like Haridwar. This is usually done when one goes for performing last rites of a family member in Haridwar and to pour the ashes in River Ganga there. However, this can be done at any time. There one has to search for the person with whom his family has kept his family tree records. The person then can ask for the existing details or addition or modification of any family members details like date of birth or date of expiration, addition of names and birth date of new members in the family, etc.

Comment: If you are a North Indian brahmin, there is a strong possibility that your family tree is also maintained in Haridwar. Check with the older members of your family.

Comment: @Aby - Yes , and also one can find his family tree in "Kashi" .The pandya people over there have very old hand written books , in that all the records are kept.

Comment: As said by @Aby and Pushkar in north India since most people go to Hariwar or Kashi for Asthi Pravah after cremation, the pandits there have a detailed record of their extended families. Not sure if there is some such system in Kanchi or any other southern place of prominence. Even if some distant relative from your family comes to these pilgrim spots it is likely that they may have your record since the entire extended family tree is refreshed here every time someone visits.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan How Sharma is determined? Many boys say different names when they say Sharma while reciting Abhivataye.

Comment: @NarayanaSharma Some people have two names given at birth: a Hindu name used in rituals, and a legal name used for official purposes like passports and the like.  So when saying the Abhivadaye they will say their Hindu name.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan Some people use their great grand father's name as Sharma?

Comment: @NarayanaSharma Yeah, sometimes people are named after their grandfather, great-grandfather or other family member for their Hindu name, and then given some other name for legal purposes.